# PHP, MySQL table query syntax error?

Tags: php

I hope someone can help see what's wrong here:
I have a form with two field `EMAIL` and `PASSWORD` that opens a php page where I intend to run a simple query on a table.
I get an error message that makes no sense:
`You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@gmail.com' at line 1`.
The email address I entered in this case did end with '@gmail.com'
Here's the code:

```
<?php
$dbhost = 'somewhere.net';
$dbuser = 'someUser';
$dbpass = 'pass';

$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die ('Error connecting to mysql');

$dbname = 'medreunten_db1';
mysql_select_db($dbname) or die(mysql_error($conn)); 

$email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);

$query = "SELECT * FROM employee WHERE email = $email";
$result = mysql_query($query, $conn) or die (mysql_error($conn));
extract(mysql_fetch_assoc($result));  


while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
extract($row);
echo $row['name'];
echo $row['surname'];
echo $row['age'];
}
?>
```

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Simple table query syntax error?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7546072/simple-table-query-syntax-error)

Comment: `$query = "SELECT * FROM employee WHERE email = '$email'";` OR
`$query = "SELECT * FROM employee WHERE email = ".$email;`

Comment: yes. I ran into more problems because I inserted the mysql_real_escape_string before the db connection and I wanted to carry on in that thread, but I think I commented and that was unacceptable, so the mods deleted it and downvoated me. so i started a new question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are missing quotes around string fields:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM employee WHERE email = '$email'";
```

Additionally,

```
extract(mysql_fetch_assoc($result));
```

will fetch the first row from the database, so your while loop will start from the second row.

Comment: thanks for pointing that out, I fixed both errors and it works :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the value in quotes inside SQL string.

```
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);

$query = "SELECT * FROM employee WHERE email = '$email'";
```

(mind the extra `''` around $email)

Answer (score 0):

Your query translates to:

```
SELECT * FROM emloyee WHERE email = foo@bar.com
```

This doesn't work, you have to put strings in quotes. Change your code to the following and it will work:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM employee WHERE email = '$email'";
```

Answer (score 0):

Just single quote the variable '$email' because it varchar type value and field .
As wrote, Darhazer :)

Answer (score 0):

Full fixed code:

```
<?php
$dbhost = 'somewhere.net';
$dbuser = 'someUser';
$dbpass = 'pass';

$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die ('Error connecting to mysql');

$dbname = 'medreunten_db1';
mysql_select_db($dbname) or die(mysql_error($conn)); 

$email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);

$query = "SELECT * FROM employee WHERE email = '$email'";
$result = mysql_query($query, $conn) or die (mysql_error($conn));
extract(mysql_fetch_assoc($result));  


while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
extract($row);
echo $row['name'];
echo $row['surname'];
echo $row['age'];
}
?>
```